# Which compaction strategy should I use in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

In my use case the whole data of partition will delete insert again. Can you please suggest which compaction strategy should I use

I have create table with default sizeteiredcompactionstrategy.

Also how much free disk space that I should keep.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard without knowing a lot more about your usecase on what would be ideal. Most likely LeveledCompactionStrategy from what you explained here (this is actually a better default then stcs). Conservatively for STCS ~50%, for LCS can go higher like 70%